# Removing viewcontrollers from navigation stack in the right way

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 5 view controllers(say A,B,C,D,E) in my navigation stack. ViewController E is in the top of the stack. On a button click in ViewController E, I want to move to ViewController C. For that I am using the following code.

```
NSMutableArray *navigationarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[navigationarray removeObjectAtIndex:4];
[navigationarray removeObjectAtIndex:3];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationarray;
[navigationarray release];
```

Is there a better way to do this, where I can check which viewController is being removed from the navigation array

Edit: In this case, could I check whether the viewcontroller being removed `isKindOfClass` of the class of the particular view controller like

```
if ([[navigationarray objectAtIndex:4] isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Popping view controller from navigation controller is the easy way. This will remove VC E and D.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewControllerC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Found this one helpful too.. `[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:4] animated:YES];`